# Rails bootstrap gem import vs require

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, bootstrap-4

I wanted to use in my rails project bootstrap framework. I used this github repository/instruction to do it: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem.
In the instruction it is underlined that I need to change my application.css extension to css.scss and use only import statements (delete all: //= require). How can I include in my application other css files? With require I could simply type //= require tree . but in this case I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `require_tree .` but the css files included this way is not compiled by sass and does not have access to sass variables and mixins defined in other files.

The recommended solution is to create one single file (say main.scss) and import all files that require access to site-wide sass resources (e.g. bootstrap variables and mixins). Then you import this one file in application.scss. And you can leave your `require tree .` there to pick up the rest of the files.